# Object reference error in unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, nunit, viewmodel

i have a controller action

```
  [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult CreateFocus(FocusFormModel focus)
    {
        var errors = focusService.CanAddFocus(Mapper.Map<FocusFormModel, Focus>(focus)).ToList();

        ModelState.AddModelErrors(errors);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            focusService.CreateFocus(Mapper.Map<FocusFormModel, Focus>(focus));
            var createdfocus = focusService.GetFocus(focus.FocusName);
            return RedirectToAction("Focus", new { id = createdfocus.FocusId });
        }
        return View("CreateFocus", focus);
    }
```

This action is working fine but when i am writing unit test  it is showing error

Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object

the uni test is

```
 [Test]
    public void Create_Focus()
    {
        // Arrange                    
        GroupController controller = new GroupController(groupService);
        // Act


        FocusFormModel focus = new FocusFormModel();
           focus.GroupId  = 1;
            focus.FocusName = "t";
            focus.Description = "t";

        Mapper.CreateMap<FocusFormModel, Focus>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.CreateFocus(focus);
          Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"]);
     }
```

My Model  is described below

```
public class Focus
{
    public int FocusId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FocusName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }



    public Focus()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

and i am writing my  view model as

```
public class FocusFormModel
{
    public int FocusId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FocusName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public FocusFormModel()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Can any one please help me

Comment: Would be helpful to know which line is throwing the null reference exception, or see a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This line actually provides 2 chances to get null reference exception:

```
var errors = focusService.CanAddFocus(Mapper.Map<FocusFormModel, Focus>(focus)).ToList();
```

first of all `focusService` might be `null`

if focusService is not null then method call `CanAddFocus(Mapper.Map<FocusFormModel, Focus>(focus))` might return `null`

That are just assumptions.
As Greg Smith said stack trace would be very helpful here.